# Performance between substring and date cast SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have this SQL code that generate the same result. which one is most efficient?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(transaccion_day, 1, 7) FROM my_table

SELECT to_char(to_date(transaccion_day,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM') FROM my_table
```

- The content of transaccion_day is something like this: '2022-06-09'
- The result is something like: '2022-06'

Comment: The real question is: why do you store a DATE value in a `varchar` column? That is a huge mistake to begin with.

Comment: Maybe having an index on a Timestamp data type and using a range query on it is simply the faster one. (even in case you take the worst path of storing it as a string, index + like query is better).

Comment: ***1).*** What data type is that column?  Using `VARCHAR` is a huge mistake.  ***2).*** If it's a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`, then use inbuilt functions to round down to the start of the month.  Such as `DATE_TRUNC('month', transaccion_day)`.  ***3).*** Performance questions should be answerable by testing it for yourself.  If I said one was faster, would you just naively trust me, or would you check?  Skip the middleman, just check it yourself.

Comment: In the source table the column is VARCHAR type i cant change it. 
it doesn't depend on me

Comment: Then, simply use a like query on an indexed colum. ie: SELECT * FROM my_table where transaccion_day like '2022-06%';

Comment: but i need group by 'YYYY-MM' @CetinBasoz

Comment: like '2022-06%' select only the dates falling in 2022-06-xx

Comment: VARCHAR for a date (or timestamp) is a great recipe for garbage in your database. How do handle this garbage? When the data is valid (after cleanup), you can use ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN to change the datatype.

Comment: message received tks!

Comment: No need to worry, will perform about the same. (As long as there's no WHERE or JOIN or ORDER BY.)

Answer (score 0):

It is most efficient with substring because in the second option you need to do two converts

Comment: Of course not. You don't need any function at all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be a text column (I hope not), then simply use a like query. It would utilize the existing index on the column. ie:

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table 
where transaccion_day like '2022-06%';
```

Comment: '2022-06' was an example. this is variable

Comment: @AndresMarin and I used as a hard coded value as an example. It can be a variable.